# Documents "disappearing" from mongodb collection after node loading routine is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Being new to mongodb and node, this particular issue is just driving me crazy:

I have written a small module, which reads an .csv file, makes it into a JSON array, and loads it into a mongodb collection one record at a time in a loop.
As I run this in debug, and set a breakpoint at "var v = i;" line, I can query the mongo collection, and see a fully populated records appear one after another.

However, as soon as the loop is finished - ALL records' data is gone!
The actual records are still all there, but they all empty. The data which I just saw in each record is no longer in those records.

It may be some wired scoping issue, but, being new, I just can not tell what that is.

Here is my code:

```
exports.excelFileParser = function(fileName, tabName, metadataFields){
    var assert = require('assert');
    console.log(metadataFields);
    if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');

    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var _ = require('underscore');

    var fs = require('fs');

    var Converter=require("csvtojson").core.Converter;

    var  distinctDataFields;

    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/datamanager-03-test';

    var fileName = 'clean_file.csv';

    //fs.writeFileSync(fileName, newCsvLines);

    var csvFileName=fileName;
    var fileStream=fs.createReadStream(csvFileName);
//new converter instance
    var csvConverter=new Converter({constructResult:true});

    //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished
    csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function(jsonObj){
        //console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object
        makeRecords(jsonObj);

    });

    function makeRecords(result){
        console.log(result.length);

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connection established to', url);

                var collectionName = 'DC_Facilities';

                db.open(function(err, client){
                    client.createCollection(collectionName, function(err, col) {
                    });

                    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

                    for(var i =0;i < result.length; i++){

                        var dataRecord = result[i];

                        collection.insert(dataRecord);

                        var v = i;
                    }
                    console.log("finished");
                    db.close();
                });
            }
        });
    }

    fileStream.pipe(csvConverter);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection.insert` is an asynchronous function, so you're calling `db.close()` before any of them have a chance to complete. You also don't need to call `createCollection` as the collection will be created for you if it doesn't already exist.

So your code should look something like this instead, so that `db.close()` isn't called until all the `insert` operations have completed:

```
db.open(function(err, client){
    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    var inserted = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        var dataRecord = result[i];
        collection.insert(dataRecord, function(err) {
            if (++inserted == result.length) {
                console.log("finished");
                db.close();
            }
        });
    }
});
```